# Constantly misplacing and losing things

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, segulah

In general, but especially lately, I tend to misplace and lose things. I can have a kippa on my head, and then it's gone. In our house, there are at least 15 missing kippot and 5 pairs of tzitzit at any one time. We can spend HOURS looking, turning over sofas and rooting through every drawer, and the kippa we had 2 minutes ago doesn't turn up until years later. I can have a bottle of antacid on my desk, and then I just can't find it. I look over the whole house and it just doesn't show up. It really feels bizarre, beyond even the explanation of ADHD.

In keeping with "tamim ti'hiyu" (so nothing superstitious please) are there any sources that deal with, or give advice around this phenomena of losing things? Is it a sign or message from Above, are there any 'segulot'; in general: is there any discussion about the phenomena of losing things in any Torah sources, ancient or contemporary? Thank you.

Comment: I am aware of Rabbi Meir's prayer for finding things, but this is more focussed on losing things. Any comments about "just get a clip" will be a bit of a waste of time because all that does is delay the inevitable :)

Comment: Have you been eating a lot of olives lately?

Comment: @יהושעק I phrased the question in a personal way to illustrate the question as an example, but as per rules of the site, let's keep it general. What have olives got to do with anything?

Comment: Eating olives without a certain kavannah taught by the Arizal is known to cause forgetfulness https://outorah.org/p/50597

Comment: When it happens to me I take it as a message from above that I have to be more careful :->

Comment: There are at least 12 advices here regarding forgetfulness https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Sefer_Hamidot

Comment: @mbloch yeah, I agree with that sentiment overall. Sometimes though, forgetfulness is outside our control.